# beyond compare with `git difftool --dir-diff` -- Hitting an issue with sym-links

Tags: git, diff, beyondcompare

Setup a new git repo and add some files:

```
[Feb-09 18:35][Desktop]$ mkdir exampleForStackOverflow
[Feb-09 18:35][Desktop]$ cd exampleForStackOverflow/

[Feb-09 18:35][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/Desktop/exampleForStackOverflow/.git/

[Feb-09 18:35][exampleForStackOverflow]$ touch foo.txt
[Feb-09 18:35][exampleForStackOverflow]$ touch bar.txt
[Feb-09 18:35][exampleForStackOverflow]$ touch baz.txt

[Feb-09 18:36][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git add *

[Feb-09 18:36][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git commit -m "Create files"
[master (root-commit) 42bfa60] Create files
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar.txt
 create mode 100644 baz.txt
 create mode 100644 foo.txt
```

Modify the files:

```
[Feb-09 18:37][exampleForStackOverflow]$ echo "Foo" > foo.txt 
[Feb-09 18:37][exampleForStackOverflow]$ echo "Bar" > bar.txt 
[Feb-09 18:37][exampleForStackOverflow]$ echo "Baz" > baz.txt
```

Current status:

```
[Feb-09 18:38][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   bar.txt
    modified:   baz.txt
    modified:   foo.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Current diff:

```
[Feb-09 18:38][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git diff
diff --git a/bar.txt b/bar.txt
index e69de29..ebd7525 100644
--- a/bar.txt
+++ b/bar.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Bar
diff --git a/baz.txt b/baz.txt
index e69de29..a688182 100644
--- a/baz.txt
+++ b/baz.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Baz
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index e69de29..bc56c4d 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Foo
```

Now with bcompare I get the following:

```
[Feb-09 18:38][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git difftool --dir-diff
```

[image]

**This is clearly not the expected behaviour.  The files do not align so differences cannot be seen**.

---

I am running:

```
[Feb-09 18:44][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git --version
git version 2.7.1

[Feb-09 18:44][exampleForStackOverflow]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Beyond Compare: `Version 4.1.3 (build 20814)`

git config:

```
[Feb-09 18:45][exampleForStackOverflow]$ git config --list
color.ui=true
user.name=FOO
user.email=BAR@BAZ.com
log.decorate=full
diff.tool=bc3
difftool.bc3=trustExitCode
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3=trustExitCode
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

---

**Question:** (From [Ismail Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281108/ismail-badawi)) What does this have to do with symlinks?

**Answer:** Sorry the screenshot isn't extremely clear but the files on the right hand side are symlinks.  See below:

```
[Feb-09 18:52][exampleForStackOverflow]$ cd /tmp/git-difftool.RWDqE/right
[Feb-09 18:52][right]$ ll
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 BAZ BAZ_g 54 Feb  9 18:51 bar.txt -> /home/BAZ/Desktop/exampleForStackOverflow/bar.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 BAZ BAZ_g 54 Feb  9 18:51 baz.txt -> /home/BAZ/Desktop/exampleForStackOverflow/baz.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 BAZ BAZ_g 54 Feb  9 18:51 foo.txt -> /home/BAZ/Desktop/exampleForStackOverflow/foo.txt
```

Comment: What does this have to do with symlinks?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: Updated

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In addition to sixtyfootersdude's suggestion, another option is to make Beyond Compare follow symbolic links. This will align symlinks with files of the same name.

In the **Folder Compare**, click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
Go to the **Handling** tab.
Check **Follow symbolic links**.

To make this affect all new sessions, change the dropdown at the bottom of the dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Also update session defaults** before you click OK.

---

Snapshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice.  I like this solution even better.  I looked for this option in Bcompare but couldn't find it.  *Since you work for scooter*: Why isn't' the rules button available from the top menu?  Maybe under tools?

Comment: From the top menu on Windows or Linux, open **Session > Session Settings**, then go to the **Comparison** tab to get to the same place as the Rules toolbar button. On Mac the menu item is **Beyond Compare > Session Settings**.

Comment: Thanks! Also remember to pick "Ignore Folder Structure" if you want a plain list of all changed files.

Answer (score 24):

Using this will work:

```
git difftool --dir-diff --no-symlinks
```

From the [git doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool/2.5.1):

> --[no-]symlinks
>
> git difftool's default behavior is create symlinks to the working tree
>   when run in --dir-diff mode and the right-hand side of the comparison
>   yields the same content as the file in the working tree.
>
> Specifying --no-symlinks instructs git difftool to create copies
>   instead. --no-symlinks is the default on Windows.

Comment: This works well for viewing the differences. But beware that this method does not allow you to edit your files (as they're only temporary copies).